Android Studio: Error while downloading chaquopy-libgfortran
I've tried to use Python on my Android app using Chaquopy. But I've got some error as I listed bellow. I don't know what's wrong since the error not showing anything. Did I do something wrong with the pip install or there is some alternative to do this task?
Collecting chaquopy-libgfortran==4.9
  Downloading https://chaquo.com/pypi-13.1/chaquopy-libgfortran/chaquopy_libgfortran-4.9-0-py3-none-android_21_x86_64.whl (541 kB)
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kezia\Downloads\PersonalApp\app\build\python\env\debug\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 425, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "C:\Users\Kezia\Downloads\PersonalApp\app\build\python\env\debug\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 507, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
  File "C:\Users\Kezia\Downloads\PersonalApp\app\build\python\env\debug\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 62, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)
  File "C:\Users\Kezia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 454, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
Exception:

  File "C:\Users\Kezia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 498, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "C:\Users\Kezia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Users\Kezia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "C:\Users\Kezia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kezia\Downloads\PersonalApp\app\build\python\env\debug\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 188, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\Kezia\Downloads\PersonalApp\app\build\python\env\debug\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 185, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "C:\Users\Kezia\Downloads\PersonalApp\app\build\python\env\debug\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 335, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "C:\Users\Kezia\Downloads\PersonalApp\app\build\python\env\debug\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 179, in resolve
    discovered_reqs.extend(self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req))
  File "C:\Users\Kezia\Downloads\PersonalApp\app\build\python\env\debug\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 362, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "C:\Users\Kezia\Downloads\PersonalApp\app\build\python\env\debug\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 314, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    abstract_dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(req)
  File "C:\Users\Kezia\Downloads\PersonalApp\app\build\python\env\debug\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 413, in prepare_linked_requirement
    local_file = unpack_url(
  File "C:\Users\Kezia\Downloads\PersonalApp\app\build\python\env\debug\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 197, in unpack_url
    file = get_http_url(
  File "C:\Users\Kezia\Downloads\PersonalApp\app\build\python\env\debug\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 126, in get_http_url
    from_path, content_type = _download_http_url(
  File "C:\Users\Kezia\Downloads\PersonalApp\app\build\python\env\debug\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 223, in _download_http_url
    for chunk in download.chunks:
  File "C:\Users\Kezia\Downloads\PersonalApp\app\build\python\env\debug\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\progress_bars.py", line 166, in iter
    for x in it:
  File "C:\Users\Kezia\Downloads\PersonalApp\app\build\python\env\debug\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\utils.py", line 15, in response_chunks
    for chunk in response.raw.stream(
  File "C:\Users\Kezia\Downloads\PersonalApp\app\build\python\env\debug\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 564, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "C:\Users\Kezia\Downloads\PersonalApp\app\build\python\env\debug\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 529, in read
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "C:\Users\Kezia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\Kezia\Downloads\PersonalApp\app\build\python\env\debug\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 430, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='chaquo.com', port=443): Read timed out.
Chaquopy: Exit status 2

> Task :app:generateDebugPythonRequirements FAILED
Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugPythonRequirements'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\Kezia\Downloads\PersonalApp\app\build\python\env\debug\Scripts\python.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1 


This is my build.gradle file used on my project and I think there is nothing wrong with it.
      python {
        version "3.8"
        buildPython "C:/Users/Kezia/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe"
        pip{
          install "numpy"
          install "opencv-python"
        }
      }


There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the server at the moment. Are you able to access those chaquo.com URLs in a browser? If your internet connection uses a proxy, you may need to use pip.options to pass a --proxy argument. Or if your connection is censored, you may need to use a VPN.

I've tried to access chaquo.com and it's working fine. How do I add the pip.options to pass a --proxy?

See the link in my previous comment.

I found the problem, since I used gradle version 8.4 seems like it's not support Chaquopy yet. So I use gradle version 8.3 and it's working now. Thanks a lot for your help anyway, really appreciate it!

I found the problem, since I used gradle version 8.4 seems like it's not support Chaquopy yet. So I use gradle version 8.3 and it's working now.
